# Illegal invocation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I don't know why this happend, I think this is impossible, or very difficult at least.

This is the code:

```
function clonar (obj) {

    var clonado = obj;
        return obj;

} 

var getter  = clonar(document.getElementById);

var getting = clonar(getter)

document.__proto__.getElementById = function (element) {

        return getting(element);

};

document.getElementById('wz-notification');
```

When this script is executed, I get a `TypeError: Illegal invocation`. I don't know why this is failing, and which is the cause of this error. At least, in Chrome, the console doesn't tell me what is failing. I think the problem is call the native function code from `getElementById` inside a new function which overwrite the native function `getElementById`.

Thank's advance!

Comment: Regardless of all the other problems with this approach, I hope you realise that `getter`, `getting` and `document.getElementById` all point to the same function (before it's overwritten)? (e.g. `console.log(getter === getting, getting === document.getElementById);` => `true true`). You're basically writing `var getter = document.getElementById, getting = getter;`

Comment: `getElementById()` wants to know the document from which it was invoked. Your `getting` is the right function, but detached from the `document`. You would need to do `return getting.call(document, element)`. But then why not just do `return document.getElementById(element)`?

Comment: As a sidenote: there is no need to access the `__proto__` property here, which is not supported everywhere. You can use the `prototype` property of the constructor instead: `Document.prototype.getElementById`